# What would be the most appropriate collection to use for this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

What would be the most appropriate collection to use for this scenario, based on the latest version of .NET/C#? I need to return a mapping of group id's with user id's. So consider a mapping like the example below where group 111 has 2 users 222 and 444:

```
111 222
111 444
555 222
```

A KeyValuePair would not be the most efficient b/c the data reflects a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: You can use Linq and do a groupBy

Comment: From your statement, "consider a mapping like the example below where group 111 has 2 users 222 and 444", this implies a one-to- many relationship, and use KeyValuePairs<int, List<int>>, so keyvaluepair with key 111 would have list with 222, 444 and keyvaluepair with key 555 would have list with 222

Comment: how do you obtain that data? With Linq you can create an IGrouping<Tkey, TElement> which is handy.

Comment: Also  linq's `ToLookup`

Comment: If you need to do lookup on both IDs, you can use two dictionaries

Answer (score 3):

The data structure you want is called "multimap", "multidictionary", or "multivaluedictionary" depending on who you ask.

There are lots of implementations of such; do a web search and you'll find some. For example:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary/

https://www.dotnetperls.com/multimap

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that the `LookUp` class isn't fully public, but you can use Linq to create it:

```
public class GroupUserid {
    public int group;
    public int userid;
}

var rawdata = List<GroupUserid>();
var groupMembership = rawdata.ToLookup(d => d.group, d => d.userid);
```

Then you can lookup the members of a group with:

```
var membersIn111 = groupMembership[111];
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to find out is the users in a group and whether a specific user is in a given group most efficiently (i.e. for probably thousands of users), but you don't need to be that efficient in determining what groups a single user is in, you might also consider using

```
Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> users = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>();

// Adding a new group:
users[newGroup] = new HashSet<int>();

// Adding a new user to the group:
users[newGroup].Add(newUser);

// Then to find all users in a group:
HashSet<int> usersInAGroup = users[aGroup];

// If you want to know very fast if a specific user is in this group, then:
if (usersInAGroup.Contains(aUser)) {/* yes, the given user is in this group */};
```

HashSet is particularly optimized for the Contains() operation on a lot of elements.